Grounding with Google Search with gemini-2.0-flash-exp
I am trying to change LLM model (Grounding with Google Search). We plan on changing our service LLM model from gemini-1.5-pro-002 to gemini-2.0-flash-exp. However, when I changed the model to a pre-test, I get the following error:

400 Unable to submit request because Please use google_search field instead of google_search_retrieval field.. Learn more: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/model-reference/gemini'

I have modified from google_search_retrieval to google_search. But other errors occurred like below. One of them was

No, Object

But there were others
My question is: Does gemini-2.0-flash-exp model not apply Grounding with Google Search?
I didn't find gemini-2.0-flash-exp in the API list.

I'm using the Node.js SDK for the Gemini API. I encountered the same error that was resolved by changing the googleSearchRetrieval parameter to googleSearch.
See Gemini 2.0 Flash (experimental).
  const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({
    model: 'gemini-2.0-flash-exp',
    tools: [
-     {
-       googleSearchRetrieval: {
-         dynamicRetrievalConfig: {
-           mode: DynamicRetrievalMode.MODE_DYNAMIC,
-           dynamicThreshold: 0.7,
-         },
-       },
-     },
+     { googleSearch: {} },
    ],
  });

